# Use YQL to Pull US Treasury Bonds Rates Summary

Tags: yql, yahoo-finance

Is there a way to use the YQL console to pull the information displayed on the [Yahoo Bonds Summary Page](http://finance.yahoo.com/bonds)

I will be using PHP to make a cURL request and retrieve the information in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Although one could manually type the following link :

[This Link Is Your Requirement](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fbonds%22%20and%20xpath%3D%27%2F%2F%2a%5B%40id%3D%22yficl%22%5D%27)

or

type the following query on the yql console :

**select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/bonds" and xpath='//*[@id="yficl"]'**

You can also extract the json file directly by using their restful api by writing the following link:

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/bonds" and xpath='//*[@id="yficl"]'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=